# illegalargumentexception - Project running on Netbeans but not on Tomcat as War file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, war

I made a project on Netbeans on my local machine with JDK 1.7 (32-bit)
On running the application (using tomcat 8.0 server on netbeans), it works perfectly on `http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1`.

I copied the war file from the dist directly and transferred it to my Windows VM server with tomcat 8.0 and jdk 1.8 installed (64-bit). Then the war file was uploaded through tomcat's manager web app.

*Note: 'localhost:8080/' and 'localhost:8080/manager' ran without any issue.*

However, when I go and run the application (`http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1`) - it throws the following errors.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.validateImport(Node.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.addImport(Node.java:593)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parsePageDirective(Parser.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:458)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1782)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:136)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The `<%page import %>` I have in my JSPs are 'java.util.*' and 2 java classes which are part of my project. Rest my java classes import some 'java.' packages

Additional info:

- I have set 'Path' environment variable to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.8\bin'
- I have tried including 'org.apache.jasper.jar' to my project (& war) too
- jdbc4.jar is also imported in library

What seems to be the problem? I am unable to make out the source of the problem.
Is it because of 32-bit vs 64-bit? or jdk 1.7 vs 1.8? or missing environment variable? or problem in  tomcat configuration? something else?

Comment: Could it be an issue with Tomcat's 'compilerSourceVM' setting? By default Tomcat will compile JSPs using Java 1.6. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem was in my import statement, which included:

**Original code**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" import="java.util.*,mypackage.one.*,mypackage.two.*;"%>
```

The issue was the `;` at the end of the import statement!

**Corrected code:**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" import="java.util.*,mypackage.one.*,mypackage.two.*"%>
```

Comment: just started running into this issue after upgrading Tomcat...see more here: [Bug 57099 – loose parsing of import attribute in page directive screws up SMAP output](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57099) (relevant to Tomcat 7.0.57 onwards or 8.0.15 onwards)

Comment: just remove the semicolon at the listReports.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Use Tomcat 7.0.21 some tomcat version giving this error, I have also faced the same issue with version 7.0.59 .